# How to show ExoPlayer in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

In my application I want show ExoPlayer in RecyclerView and for this I write below codes. 
I want show video thumbnail on video and write below codes in XML: 
My recyclerview **items layout:**

```xml
            <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                android:id="@+id/blueVideoPlayer"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_150mdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_150mdp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:use_artwork="true"
                app:resize_mode="zoom"
                app:use_controller="false"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

And write below codes in **RecyclerView adapter**:

```kotlin
class ChatAdapter constructor(val context: Context, val items: MutableList<Result>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var binding: ItemChatBinding
    private val userToken by lazy { GoodPrefs.getInstance().getString(USER_TOKEN, "") }
    private var player: ExoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        binding = ItemChatBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = position

    override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()

    inner class ViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        fun bind(item: Result) {
            binding.apply {
                //Layouts
                if (item.toUserId?.id == PHYSICIAN_DATA?.id) {
                    blueLay.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    blueDate.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    blueBubble.isVisible = item.message != null
                    doctorStatus.isVisible = !(item.deliveredAt == null && item.seenAt == null)
                    whiteLay.isVisible = false
                    whiteDate.isVisible = false
                    whiteBubble.isVisible = false
                    meStatus.isVisible = false
                } else {
                    blueLay.isVisible = false
                    blueDate.isVisible = false
                    blueBubble.isVisible = false
                    doctorStatus.isVisible = false
                    whiteLay.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    whiteDate.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    whiteBubble.isVisible = item.message != null
                    meStatus.isVisible = !(item.deliveredAt == null && item.seenAt == null)
                }
                //Message
                if (item.message != null) {
                    whiteTxt.text = item.message?.replace("\"", "")
                    whiteTxt.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    blueTxt.text = item.message?.replace("\"", "")
                    blueTxt.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    whiteTxt.visibility = View.GONE
                    blueTxt.visibility = View.GONE
                }
                //File
                if (item.chatFile != null) {
                    whiteFileLay.isVisible = true
                    blueFileLay.isVisible = true
                    fileVisibilityMode(item.chatFile.type!!)

                    when (item.chatFile.type) {
                        IMAGE -> {
                            whiteLoading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            blueLoading.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                            ApiClient.getInstance().apisUseCase().getAvatarImage(userToken, item.chatFile.id!!)
                                .applyIoScheduler()
                                .subscribe({
                                    whiteLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                                    blueLoading.visibility = View.GONE

                                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                        if (it.code() == 200) {
                                            if (it.body() != null) {
                                                val decodedBytes: ByteArray = Base64.decode(it.body()!!.data!!.file, Base64.DEFAULT)
                                                whiteImg.load(decodedBytes)
                                                blueImg.load(decodedBytes)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    whiteLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                                    blueLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                                })

                        }
                        VIDEO -> {
                            whiteVideoPlayer.player = player
                            blueVideoPlayer.player = player

                            val mediaItem: MediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(fileUrl(item.chatFile.id!!))
                            Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!).postDelayed(
                                    {
                                        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
                                        player.prepare()
                                    }, 200
                                )
                        }
                        VOICE -> {

                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    whiteFileLay.isVisible = false
                    blueFileLay.isVisible = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun fileUrl(id: Int): String {
        return "${BASE_URL}core/shared/files/$id/downloads?token=${userToken.replace("Bearer ", "")}"
    }
}
```

But when run application show me just black color instead of videos! 
Not show me any video, just show black color!

How can I fix it?

Comment: you need to use view pager with fragment adapter.....if you use recycler it will create much problem in rendering video and it recreate view on runtime and may your video get pause or coincide with multiple video

Comment: where do you player.play()    ?

Comment: @seekingStillness , I don't want play video. I want just show video thumbnail from video file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This so easy, just use **Glide** library.

```
Glide.with(context).load(fileUrl("YOUR_VIDEO_URL")).into(R.id.YOUR_THUMB_IMG)
```